# rails, undefined 'raw' method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined

I am following the michael hartl book and have been doing an optional exercise that I can't seem to figure out.

I have a helper called,

```
module MicropostsHelper

  def wrap(content)
    sanitize(raw(content.split.map{ |s| wrap_long_string(s) }.join(' ')))
  end
  private
    def wrap_long_string(text, max_width = 30)
      zero_width_space = "&#8203;"
      regex = /.{1,#{max_width}}/
      (text.length < max_width) ? text : 
                                  text.scan(regex).join(zero_width_space)
    end
end
```

which I'm trying to wrap content that should be a string from user input. In my controller I have,

```
def create
    flash[:notice] = "[][] is...", params[:micropost][:content]
    cleaned = wrap(params[:micropost][:content])
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(cleaned)
    ...
```

however I keep getting undefined method 'raw'. Could someone explain why?

is there an api that shows examples of methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `string.html_safe` or `r 'string'` in the html views

Comment: raw is a helper, you either need to include into your model or use html_safe as Sairam suggests.

Answer (score 2):

You might simply use wrap method directly in html.erb file:

Was:

```
<span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
```

Became:

```
<span class="content"><%= wrap(micropost.content) %></span>
```

Comment: Not only does this use the code that Michael provides, it also speaks to an issue I had when doing it as the OP was trying; wrapping the content before persisting that is. If you modify content purely based on styling and appearance before persisting to storage, you might be shooting yourself in the foot when it comes to displaying on a different screen size.

Comment: One of the nice things about Bootstrap is its ability to change the layout of the site based on the screen size, http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive, and while the above may work for the computer/browser version of the site, it's generally best practice to do view formatting in the view. This will allow you to modify it based on screen size, should you choose to expand whatever application you decide to build.

Comment: For that reason, I would recommend choosing this one as the correct answer.

Comment: It is not about just adapting to the different screens. It is more about the idea, that you should handle all the view issues on the frontend, with css and js. I think this wrapping is just simply wrong.